# Can't make desktop icon for Minecraft

Tags: launcher

I have been trying to make a Minecraft launcher icon on my Linux desktop and I have had no success. I have tried using a text editor and pasted this text:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=False
Exec=java-jar "/root/.minecraft/launcher.jar"
Name=Minecraft Launcher 
Comment=Minecraft
Icon=/root/.minecraft/icons/icon.jpg
```

Comment: You have to provide full pathnames for Exec and Icon lines. And the .desktop file should go into `~/.local/share/applications`.

Comment: ok i will do that

Comment: still not working

Comment: the file has not changed

Comment: i just tried and nothing changed

Comment: however, you forgot a space in "java -jar"... and you didn't take out the "#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open"

Comment: Are you logged into the root account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**change this:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=java -jar ~/.minecraft/launcher.jar
Name=Minecraft
Comment=Minecraft
Icon=~/.minecraft/icons/icon.jpg
```

**to this: (using the proper username)**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=java -jar "/home/jamesestes/.minecraft/launcher.jar"
Name=Minecraft
Comment=Minecraft
Icon=/home/jamesestes/.minecraft/icons/icon.jpg
```

And the .desktop file should go into `~/.local/share/applications`.

Comment: do i need a comment?

Comment: the comment line and also the icon just now showed up but its still not launching

Comment: the comment line the one that says: Comment=Minecraft and it stall says error launching application

Comment: not working still i may just give up on it

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: Copy/paste into your question please... however, you forgot a space in "java -jar"... and you didn't take out the "#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open"

Comment: and where do I place the file if i want to add it as an application

Comment: See the last line of my answer. Please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!